# How to receive and send message to specific channel in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working on a command where a bot responds to `!name Barty` with `Hello Barty`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def name(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(f"hello {arg}")
```

However, the problem I am facing is that the bot responds to `!name foo` in any channel, and I only want it to respond in certain channels.

I tried:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id == 1234567:
    @bot.command()
    async def name(ctx, arg):
      await ctx.send(f"hello {arg}")
```

This isn't working and I'm out of ideas.

How can I send a command to a given channel and get a response from it?

Comment: What you currently have in your second snippet is: "*if channel id equals 1234567, then define the command `name`*". But this doesn't work for two reasons: the function isn't called and commands should be top-level functions (i.e. not nested). Are you intending to apply this "channel restriction" to other commands as well (not just "name")?

Comment: @TrebledJ Correct, I was planning to add maybe 3 functions that works the same way as `async def name(ctx, args):` but some will have more args etc `async def birthday(ctx, args, args2):` - But yes. I want to apply the "channel restriction" to other commands aswell. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the define code out of the IF statement:

```
@bot.command()
async def name(ctx, args):
    await ctx.send("hello {}".format(args)
```

When you've done that, you should be able to do;

```
if (message.channel.id == 'channel id'): 
    await message.channel.send('message goes here')

else:
    # handle your else here, such as null, or log it to ur terminal
```

Could also check out the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io

**Once you make the command, make the IF statement inside of that.**

Comment: Oh, instead of message.channel.id I would just replace to ctx.channel.id in that case?

Comment: Yeah dude give that a shot and let me know how you get on

Answer (score 2):

message.channel.id now needs to be an integer, not a string so you don't need to use ''

```
    if (message.channel.id == 1234567): 
      await message.channel.send('message goes here')

  else:
    # handle your else here, such as null, or log in to ur terminal
```

Comment: can you give more details? maybe some code snippets